# How do I change font type but not size in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts

The only way that I have learned to change the font of text in java so far is using new Font(font name, Font.PLAIN, font size) and I was wondering if there is a way that I could just simply change the font type while not effecting any other aspects of it. This is because I want to be able to change the font type of all componenets of the GUI using one method using input from a combo box in the settings section of the program and it would be a pain to go back through all of the components and search for their exact font size.

Comment: see Font.deriveFont

Comment: What front end library are you using? Since this might differ quit a bit depending on the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many components, with different font sizes, register a PropertyChangeListener on each component (that displays text) as you create it. Then the propertyChange() method of the listener should get the font of the source and change it using deriveFont() to create a font of the new style.

Answer (score -1):

You can use deriveFont(style) to change the font with a new style. This creates a new Font object.

Comment: But it does not solve his problem of changing the style of all of his components while preserving the size of all of them (it is assumed that there can be different sizes in different components)